# What is the difference between future and shared_future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

What is the difference between `future` and `shared_future`?
In what cases  we must use `shared_future` instead of `future`?

I was trying to find good documentation that will contrast these two features of C++11, and I could not find an answer (easy/readable at least) on the web.

This is my current understanding of the differences

1. `future` object could be queried only once for the `get()`.
2. `shared_future` could be queried any number of times.

use case: 
If multiple threads are dependent on the result of an asynchronous task, then we must use `shared_future`. 
If the future object needs be queried multiple times in the same thread then we must use `shared_future` instead.

Any more information, gotchas or general guidelines are welcome...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The motivation for these two future types goes back to move semantics, move-only types, and the new C++11 feature to return move-only types from ordinary functions.

In C++98/03, if you wanted to return a type from a factory function:

```
A
make_A()
{
    A a;
    // ...
    return a;
}
```

then `A` had to be `CopyConstructible`.  Then, brand new in C++11, we can return `A` even if it is not `CopyConstructible`, it need only be `MoveConstructible`.

But what happens if you try to execute `make_A` concurrently, say using futures.  Wouldn't it be a crime if you could only parallelize `make_A` if `A` is `CopyConstructible`?!  You would have to give up one optimization while chasing another!

So `future<R>` only requires `R` to be `MoveConstructible`.  But you can only get it once, because you're moving from the stored result.

But getting the same result for multiple threads is a real need too.  So `shared_future<R>` allows that, but requires `R` to be `CopyConstructible`.

Comment: So not only that R in shared_future<R> have to be copyConstructible, they are actually copied, where as in future<R>, access will not make copy and only move.
So that means, use future<R> by default, since it is faster, and use shared_future<R> when you have to.  Correct ?

Comment: @Ajeet:  That is actually the precise reasoning that came up with the naming of `future` and `shared_future`. In the beginning there was `unique_future` and `shared_future` and there was much discussion as to which one should be the "default".  And whichever should be the default, that one should be named "future".  At the time this decision was being made, move semantics was still very new to the C++ committee, and not that well understood.  I credit the C++ committee with a wise leap of faith in assigning the simpler name of "future" to "unique_future".